# VBA VlookUp with input does not fetch result, is it code error or datatype mismatch?

Tags: excel, vba, input, vlookup

---

Hi,

Currently I am trying to automate one of most time consuming excel files.
Obviously VlookUp is the issue.

Some background as fresh VBA dev:

- I am using inputbox to get specific Sheet name in order to update with it all my vlookups. Yes, this will be reoccuring every few weeks. And with all Vlookups I cannot just do it manually it would took ages.
- long story short: Vlookup with Evaluate formula is not fetching data, but respoding with beloved #VALUE! in certain cell.
- And as I am stuck with this, there will be another issue I guess, as I cannot dragdown this formula in my entire range. But this can be solved with just range i.e. BS13:BS37020, right? But this generate problem with first argument for Vlookup as it will change.

Code below:

```
Dim myValue As Variant

myValue = InputBox("Please enter sheet argument for Vlookup including apostrophe and !")


Worksheets("191207").Range("BS13").Formula = Evaluate("VLOOKUP($C13, """ & myValue & """  $C$2:$CD$92000,14,0)")
'                desired vlookup                                =VLOOKUP($C13,191207!$C$2:$CD$92000,14,0)
```

And how VlookUp in formula is diffrent than the one in VBA? Or please advise if my approach is incorrect with VlookUp.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you give us an example sheet name that you are inputting?

Comment: Sidenote: You are inputting a value that you accuired through `Evaluate` and you want to input as a `Formula` into your `Range`...So let me ask you, do you really want to input a formula? Or do you just want the returned value. Notice that there are VBA functions for that.

Comment: Hi,
@BigBen My bad, example sheet name: is 191107 or 191115
Thanks JvdV, I need this only to refer to certain sheets as they will change.
Can You elaborate what you have in mind?

Comment: What is the *exact* input, including the single quotes and the exclamation point?

Comment: What types of values are you looking up? Are they dates? Numbers? Text?

Comment: For input I understand that with evaluate I have to refer to my vlookup value as it was function, thats why I have put it like '191107'!. 
Data Types are mostly texts.

Comment: Should be `Worksheets("191207").Evaluate(...)` - specify the sheet to make sure the formula is evaluated in the right context.

Comment: @BigBen I would have to update manually a lot of Vlookups without input value. Weekly. Of course I can do it Via macro and replace it every week+/-1 or 2 days. But I'd rather have that automated only to input sheets name and let it go in background.
So I am trying to figure out how I can us input value to refer to new sheets name every time I run the macro.

Comment: If you don't specify the worksheet before the `Evaluate`, then `$C$13` in the vlookup will refer to the `ActiveSheet`... the worksheet specified is the one that `$C$13` is on.

Comment: @BigBen You're a genius. And me? Blind, didn't see that one coming. So, it should look like this?:
`Worksheets("191207").Range("BS13").Formula = Evaluate.Worksheets(""" myValue """, ("VLOOKUP($C13, $C$2:$CD$92000,14,0)"))`
Edit: obviously not, it's not that, but I got the direction. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like this is more what you want:

```
Dim myValue As Variant

myValue = InputBox("Please enter sheet name")

Worksheets("191207").Range("BS13").Formula = _
           "=VLOOKUP($C13, '" & myValue & "'!$C$2:$CD$92000,14,0)")
```

Comment: Well, sometimes simplest solutions are the best ones. Somehow I've missed that one. Thank You